# ssis script converts System.DateTime to DT_DBTIMESTAMP but does not convert to DT_DBTIMESTAMP2

Tags: c#, datetime, ssis, etl, datetime2

when i try to pass DateTime.Now value to DT_DBTIMESTAMP field via this code

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
    Output0Buffer.Dt = DateTime.Now;
}
```

it works well. but when Output0Buffer.Dt is of type DT_DBTIMESTAMP2, i receive a message:

> "The value is too large to fit in the column data area of the buffer."

[image: screenshot]

though DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 should be larger than DT_DBTIMESTAMP

is there a way to pass the value properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scale parameter is set to 0 by default

in my case it should be 7

[image]

Answer (score 2):

after searching i found this article: [Mapping C# DateTime to SQL Server datetime2 via SSIS](http://picnicerror.net/development/sql-server/mapping-c-sharp-datetime-sql-server-datetime2-ssis-2014-04-21/), ithink this is what you are looking for.

**Also you can do a workaround**

Don't change the output column type, leave it DT_DBTIMESTAMP.

And outside the script component, Add a **Data Conversion Transformation** and convert the output column to DT_DBTIMESTAMP2

Comment: tank you. i found the answer.
scale parameter is set to 0 by defauld
in my case it should be 7